# Return data based on multiple critera, including blanks, and account for duplicate entries with different values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Right so I've been bashing my head over this one for a while and I think I'm asking for too many specific things for google to get me there.

I could either be missing a very simple solution or actually asking too much.

The gist is that there is a large downloadable spreadsheet of data. The data by itself is cluttered and useless. Every month, occasionally more, someone has to download this sheet and sort through the data for what the boss actually wants to see. (See the blank data mockup except it's actually 25 columns and thousands of rows. Also the Ref is entirely RANDOM alphanumeric rather than LLL###. "Keep" is a stand in for data on the sheet we can use as a filter.)

[image: Original Data Mockup]

All of this data is copied into a separate "raw data" tab and the end result below is its own "clean" tab.

I've been making a "conversion sheet" for it because the filtering is a very long manual job. So far I've been pretty successful with almost the entire sheet save for one final column. The final result would look like this:

[image: Final]

The first three columns here are filled out with "=FILTER(A:A,$D:$D="keep")", amended for each column.

Now you can see we've got all our different "a" charges and their corresponding charges (these do change i was just lazy on the mockup), and the "b" charges associated with the reference. Some references, like abc123, have no b charge so the cell is blank. Some References have more than one "b" charge so they're listed in order they appear (which works fine because that means they do line up that way."

The issue I run into is getting this column to fill out without manual interference. I'd like it to fill out dynamically like every other column, so that all anyone has to do is paste the data into the first tab. If that's not possible then I'd at least like to get it so the formula can just be copied down but so far everything either ignores the blanks so the data is unaligned, or ignores that ref sometimes has duplicate values.

So the closest I've come is using =FILTER(C:C,(G2=A:A)*(B:B="b"),""). This needs to be copied down, which is fine, but also produces spill errors where the duplicates are.

[image: SPILL errors]

No I can rework this, because of the handy outline "spill" produces it's easy enough to go down and delete everything but the first instance of spill. This gives the desired effect of returning every "item b" charge, including those with duplicate references, and those that have no "item b" remain blank. But the end users of this sheet are not very computer-inclined, let alone excel-inclined, so trying to explain that doesn't really work.

=FILTER(C:C,(B:B="b"),"") is automatic but ignores blanks so it all gets offset by the number of blanks.

Any ideas on this will be really useful. I'm not against hiding a "backend" tab to reference the data I need but I'm going in circles.

Comment: I’ll take a further look at this when I can, but first off…  FILTER() and “copied down” are generally incompatible approaches.  FILTER() is intended to return *all* the rows that match the criteria, whereas your reference to “copying down” explicitly means you are looking to interact with each row individually.  The three main array selection functions each have a unique paradigm.  XLOOKUP() finds the one first matching value, FILTER() finds *all* the matching values, and XMATCH() finds the *location* within an array of the first matching value.

Comment: Thanks, I've been playing with it a little more (a lot more...I downloaded excel onto my phone because I couldn't sleep) and managed to use an IFERROR and VLOOKUP to get the blanks registered as "0" which is fine, but obviously VLOOKUP isn't accounting for those duplicates. I've managed to make a sort of backend collection where the references are numbered and unique but then I can't get it to link back to the data I actually want.

And yes, FILTER should just produce an array which is why I used it but that formula I put in does not? Something to do with the multiple criteria I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer! It's long and it is not elegant so improvements are welcome but thanks to @Max R's suggestion of XLOOKUPS, something I've not played with before, and a "running count" array I've managed to come up with the below.

[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shLkc.png)

Thanks to the nature of arrays everything should show up in the same order so I've taken advantage of this. I'll list the formulas used in each column below.

```
K: =FILTER(A:A,($B:$B="b")) 
L: =COUNTIF(OFFSET($K$2,0,0,SEQUENCE(ROWS($K$2#)),1),$K$2#) 
M: =$K$2#&L2# 
N: =FILTER($C:$C,($B:$B="b"))
```

This first set essentially creates a new data selection of ONLY "b" charges and gives them unique identifiers.

```
O: =XLOOKUP($F$2#,$K$2#,$K$2#,0,0,1) 
P: =COUNTIF(OFFSET($O$2#,0,0,SEQUENCE(ROWS($O$2#)),1),$O$2#) 
Q: =IF($O$2#=0,0,$O$2#&$P$2#)
```

And this section determines a pattern of what lines in the table should and should not have an entry. Then it applies the identifiers again using the same method, so they correlate with our first table.

All of this leads to finally being able to input in the "item b cost" column:

```
I: =XLOOKUP($Q$2#,$M$2#,$N$2#,0,0,1)
```

I've tested this already with the data and it works great for what the users need.